# Is is possible to clone a repository with a single branch under a different name

Tags: git, github

I'm using

```
git clone --bare -b main --single-branch <internal-repo-url> internal
cd internal && git push --mirror <private-fork-url>
```

To create a private fork of an internal repository.
In this way I can pull in updates from the origin repository through another remote that is not 'origin':

```
git remote add internal <internal-repo-url>
git pull internal main
```

Is there a way for me to create a bare clone with the 'main' branch under a different name? My motivation for doing this is wanting to have the private fork's own 'main' branch distinguished from the internal repo

Comment: "to have the private fork's own 'main' branch distinguished from the internal repo" They _are_ different. The names do not confuse Git.

Comment: Nothing _prevents_ you from having as many clones with different names as you like, but it's probably not a good idea. Occasionally I find myself creating a second temporary clone e.g. for testing out a Github Action which needs to run only on the `main` branch, but then a proper fork is probably better for any repo where you are not the sole contributor.

Comment: @matt I know they are different, but the repo is a sort of like a web project starter toolkit. It would help our developers a lot to have the project "main" distinguished from the toolkit's "main".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right sequence would be:

```
git clone --bare -b main --single-branch <internal-repo-url> internal
git remote rename origin internal
git remote add origin <private-fork-url>
git branch -u origin/main
git push --mirror
```

That way, your local main branch is tied to the upstream `private-fork-url/main`, while you still have `internal/main`

Comment: This seems intuitive. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My regular workflow when forking on GitHub is this:

1. Use the regular GitHub forking functionality.
2. Locally, I check out from my GitHub repository. The `origin` remote then points to my repository (created in step 1) on GitHub.
3. Configure an additional remote `upstream` to the original repository.

This allows me to use `git rebase my-feature-branch upstream/master` in order to incorporate latest changes from there.

That said, keep in mind that there are three similar branches now: `main` (local), `origin/main` and `upstream/main`. Similarly, you can also specify where you push your work when you push and you can pick the target repository, the local reference and the remote branch independently.

Comment: I'll also consider this. Thank you.